# error al imprimir el reporte

Tags: python, mvc, xml, odoo, report

estoy haciendo un reporte avanzado en el modelo de odoo que tengo ya quedo la pantalla y si recibe informacion pero a lahora imprimir el reporte si lo descarga pero al ahora de abrirlo no muestra nada de informacion estoy usando una estuctura para darle el estilo de tabla

Adjunto codigo de python:

```
      from odoo.tools import date_utils
         from odoo.exceptions import UserError, ValidationError
         from odoo import fields, models, api



     class ReporteEspecialCartaPorte (models.TransientModel):
      _name=('reporte_mti_datos_generales_carta_porte')
 
     consignment_note_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='mti.carta.porte', string='Carta Porte')
     product_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='product.template', string='Producto')
    partner_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='res.partner', string='Remitente')
    consignee_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='res.partner', string='Consignee')
    invoice_mti = fields.Char(string='Factura')
     arrival_notification = fields.Char(string='Notificacion de llegada')


      def get_datos_generales_report(self):
       data = {
        'consignment_note_id': self.consignment_note_id,
        'product_id': self.product_id,
        'partner_id': self.partner_id,
        'consignee_id': self.consignee_id,
        'invoice_mti': self.invoice_mti,
        'arrival_notification': self.arrival_notification
        }
       return self.env.ref('mti_report_cp.action_datos_generales_report').report_action(self, data=data)


     class GeneralCard(models.AbstractModel):
    _name = 'report.datos_generales'
    @api.model
    def _get_report_values(self, docids, data=None):
        return {
            'doc:ids': docids,
            'doc_model': 'mti.carta.porte',
            'docs': self.env['mti.carta.porte'].search_read([('consignment_note_id', '==', data['consignment_note_id']),
                                                             ('product_id', '==', data['product_id'])],
                                                            ['consignment_note_id','product_id','partner_id','consignee_id','invoice_mti','arrival_notification'])
        }
```

asi es como tengo estrcturado el modelo cabe aclarar que este modelo abre un pop up y asi es como tengo el reporte en xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <odoo>
    <template id="datos_generales_report_view">
        <t t-call="web.html_container">
            <div class="header" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black">
                <h3 class="text-center"> Informe de datos generales de carta porte</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="article mt0 o_rpeort_layout_standard">
                <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <th style="width: 65%">Carta Porte</th>
                        <th class="text-center" style="width: 15%">Producto</th>
                        <th class="text-center" style="width: 20%">Remitente</th>
                        <th class="text-center" style="width: 20%">Consignatario</th>
                        <th class="text-center" style="width: 20%">Factura</th>
                        <th class="text-center" style="width: 20%">Notificacion de llegada</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <t>
                            <tr t-foreach="data" t-as="report">
                                <td><span t-esc="data['consignment_note_id']"/></td>
                                <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="report['dproduct_id']"/></td>
                                <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="report['partner_id']"/></td>
                                <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="report['consignee_id']"/></td>
                                <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="report['invoice_mti']"/></td>
                                <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="report['arrival_notification']"/></td>
                            </tr>
                        </t>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="footer o_standard_footer" style="border-top: 1px solid black;">
                <div class="row text-center">
                     <div class="col col-12 text-center">
                    <ul class="list-inline">
                        <li class="list-inline-item">Page:</li>
                        <li class="list-inline-item">
                            <span class="page"/>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-inline-item">/</li>
                        <li class="list-inline-item">
                            <span class="topage"/>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </t>
    </template>
           </odoo>
```

y asi es como tengo la estructura del reporte en xml pero a la hora de descargarlo y lo curioso es que no manda ningun error pero el reporte viene vacio que puedo hacer ahi para que no este vacio

Adjunto imagen del reporte

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]